# Using offline server in PHP

Tags: php, offline

I'm having problems using the `mail` command in PHP through an offline server.
I've used the `mail(to, subject, body)` function but the mail wasn't sent to the address. Should I be online?

Comment: mail() won't work in offline.

Comment: Try phpMailer() class... https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your problem is that you have no SMTP server installed. I suggest you to check on of these:

- [Pdf tutorial to create your own SMTP Server](http://www.outlookwise.com/Downloads/Documents/OutlookWise/OutlookWise_SMTP_Mail_Server.pdf)
- [Online tutorial](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/create-smtp-server-computer-51563.html)
- [Online tutorial #2](http://www.ehow.com/how_5653453_create-own-email-smtp.html)
- [Alternative way to find out](https://www.google.cz/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20make%20your%20own%20smtp%20server)

After successfull setting it up, you'll need to configure your php.ini too, to point at the SMTP you are using.

---

Or instead of creating your own, you can google how to use someone else's SMTP. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running code from local server then mail function will not send mail. Mail function need live mail server. You can use smtp mail to send mail from local server.

Comment: Thank you. Can u give me the exact syntax of smtp mail?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer                                                                Try this tutorial

Comment: use gmail smtp server with gmail login credentials for example it will work