# sendmail.php file isnt working right?

Tags: php, sendmail

so I'm new at this website stuff and im doing at part of my uni course, my tearcher gave me the code. 
This in my code for my sendmail.php I tested my contact form on my website and I get the 'Failure!' message that is in the code but that is all I get, nothing else. 
when it was working I would get the email but know information that was put in to the contact form and I haven't change the coding. could someone please help me? Thank you

```
<?php
/*Here you are going to declare the variables*/
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
//Save visitor name and entered message into one variable:
$formcontent="VISITOR NAME: $name\\n\\nFEEDBACK: $message";
$recipient = "denisedaykinphotography@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email\\r\\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: $email\\r\\n";
$mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\\r\\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Failure!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: Code doesn't just "stop working" you or somebody else made a change that made it stop working. - Have you done any debugging? Are you sure all the required variables are set?

Comment: if you are running this code on localhost then did you configure SMTP for localhost.

Comment: Its failing because php on a windows machine cannot send emails you will need to configure php to send via an smtpd of some description or delete all the code and use swiftmail and configure it to send via your uni email account :)

Comment: Maybe your website host disabled the mail() function because it was being abused?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your $variables outside of "strings".
meaning:

```
$name = "Bob";
"hello $name" != "hello " . $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that hosting/your computer where the script is put at the moment doesn't support sending mails.

If this is your computer, you could put use to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716458/using-offline-server-in-php/29716520#29716520) I provided in a similar thread and setting up your own SMTP server (that is the service responsible for sending emails), or using a free one from Internet.

If this is not your computer and you can not really change configs/server configuration, etc., then I suggest you to move the script somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The value of variable `$mailheader` is wrong. Now, an `echo($mailheader)` displays something like:

```
From: user@example.org\r\nReply-To: user@example.org\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n
```

which is wrong.

The header lines must be separated by the [`<CR><LF>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#/media/File:ASCII_Code_Chart-Quick_ref_card.png) pair of characters, i.e. the characters having the codes `13` and `10`. Because they are not printable, in [PHP double-quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) these characters are **encoded** as `"\r"` and `"\n"`.

The same remark about the content of you message.

Regarding this issue, the code should look like this:

```
$formcontent = "VISITOR NAME: $name\n\nFEEDBACK: $message";
$recipient = "denisedaykinphotography@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
$mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
```

These answer does not really address your problem of mails not being sent **but**, before checking the PHP configuration and other mail-related issues, make sure the values you provide to PHP [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function are correctly formatted (as explained above).